# SQL join with default attribute value

Tags: sql, join, attributes

I have a table of objects, a table defining attributes, and a table with object attribute values:

```
OBJECTS:
ID  | ...
----+-----
1   | ...
2   | ...

ATTRIBUTES:
KEY  | DEFAULT
-----+---------
a1   | xyz
a2   | abc
a3   | 123

OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES:
OBJECT_ID  | KEY  | VALUE 
-----------+------+-------
1          | a1   | abcd
1          | a2   | xyzw
2          | a3   | 12345
```

So each object can define value for its attributes, otherwise the `default` for that attribute should be used.

Now I need a select that will join all the objects with all the attributes, substituting the `default` whenever `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` record does not exist:

```
INTENDED QUERY RESULT:
OBJECT_ID  | ...  | KEY  | VALUE 
-----------+------+------+-------
1          | ...  | a1   | abcd
1          |      | a2   | xyzw
1          |      | a3   | 123 <- filled in default
2          |      | a1   | xyz <- filled in default
2          |      | a2   | abc <- filled in default
2          |      | a3   | 12345
```

How can I do this in SQL?

---

Under the fold: right now I just select

```
SELECT * FROM OBJECT LEFT JOIN OBJECTS_ATTRIBUTES ON ID = OBJECT_ID
```

But then I have to fill in the blanks manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the cartesian product of table `Objects` with `Attributes` so all objects contains all attributes.

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.key,
        COALESCE(c.value, b.default) Value
FROM    Objects a
        CROSS JOIN Attributes b
        LEFT JOIN Object_Attributes c
            ON  a.ID = c.object_id AND
                b.key = c.key
ORDER   BY a.ID, b.key
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6ddb/4)

Comment: this works on almost all RDBMS. what are you using by the way?

Comment: Postgres. Will have to work on it a bit though, this is just a minimal working example, my situation is much more complex :)

Answer (score 1):

You could get all existing entries from `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` and then add (UNION ALL) missing combinations from `OBJECTS` and `ATTRIBUTES`:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID, KEY, VALUE
FROM OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES

UNION ALL

SELECT o.ID, a.KEY, a.DEFAULT
FROM OBJECTS AS o
CROSS JOIN ATTRIBUTES AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES
  WHERE OBJECT_ID = o.ID AND KEY = a.KEY
);
```